# SpiderMonkey: Manually Calling a Constructor Function

Tags: firefox, proxy, spidermonkey

As we know we create a proxy like this.

`var proxy = new Proxy(target, handler);`

I however want to get a new proxy object by simply calling a function

`var proxy = CreateAProxy(target,handler);`

basically without using the `new` keyword. How do i proceed in spidermonkey for achieving this.

Comment: Come on guys i just need a general guideline in 4-5 sentences on how to proceed nothing more.

Comment: Stackoverflow for spidermonkey is not active. Your best bet is the irc channel #jsapi on moz irc channels. Here is mibbit, an html5 client: https://client00.chat.mibbit.com/?url=irc%3A%2F%2Firc.mozilla.org%2F%23jsapi  Another place you can try is http://ask.mozilla.org/

Comment: @Noitidart Have already tried there haven't got an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This calls for this answer:

```
function CreateAProxy(target, handler) {
  return new Proxy(target, handler);
}
```

In other words, I don't think you've explained what exactly you need and why.